# Show tooltip without double tapping for field?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

If a user is on mobile. And clicks to edit a field. He has to click twice if I have a tooltip for that field. Once to show the tooltip and then another to edit the field. I want this to just be one click like it is on a computer.

How can we make tooltip work where the user only taps once to show the tooltip AND to edit the field on mobile?

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip Title, Baby!">
  <%= f.number_field :days_challenged, value: 10 %> Day Challenge
</div>

<script>
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
</script>
```

I'm using [tooltip from bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Comment: AFAIK we can't do that. That's the tooltip issue with Bootstrap. Disabling tooltip for mobile devices is what they recommend. Check this issue for more details : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6232

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="$(this).tooltip('show')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip text" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
         div content                           
</div>
```

`onclick="$(this).tooltip('show')"` shows the tooltip when clicked.

then you can use `$(this).tooltip('hide')` method to hide it again.

for the edit part:
I'm not sure what you mean with editing the field, could you explain?

EDIT:

```
<script>
$( "target" ).click(function() {
  $(this).tooltip('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: If a user is on mobile. And clicks to edit a field. He has to click twice if I have a tooltip for that field. Once to show the tooltip and then another to edit the field. I want this to just be one click like it is on a computer.

Comment: try putting onclick="$(this).tooltip('show')" in the input, or make a script: $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').click(tooltip('show'));
})

Answer (score 0):

I found another simular tooltip UI.
You can find it [here](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

I tested it on my own phone and it shows correctly; you only have to click it once.